# How to pass a value to PHP variable from twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am passing value to a bootstarp modal form like this -

`echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN45464" data-toggle="modal" title="Add this item" class="AddBookDialog" href="#addBookDialog">`';

javascript:

```
<script>
 $(document).on("click", ".AddBookDialog", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
 $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

And receiving it in a text area like this -

```
echo '<textarea name="bookId" id="bookId"></textarea>';
```

Now my question is how to get this value into a php variable say $receivedValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this article, which explains sending a form using AJAX step by step.

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/

Comment: Note, having a form inside a bootstrap model has no consequences in how it behaves or should be handled. It's just a form :)